# Adding data to the the new worksheet in excel file using "openxl" in R

Tags: r, excel

I am having trouble with writting data to Excel using "`openxl`" package. So, I have 2 dataframes '`data`' and '`data2`' which I write to `Excel` first. Then I remove objects from `R` (due to big size of each data frame) and would like to add a 3rd `dataframe` to the new excel sheet and keep the previous 2. Here is the code:

```
data<-read_excel("AA.xlsx",sheet=2)
data2<-read_excel("AA.xlsx",sheet=3)
list1<-list("a"=data,"b"=data2)
write.xlsx(list1,file="Output.xlsx")
rm(list=ls())

data3<-read_excel("AA.xlsx",sheet=4)
#Not sure how t proceed from here onwards.
```

I have tried the following 2:

```
list2<-list("a","b","c"=data3)
write.xlsx(list2,file="Output.xlsx")
```

and

```
write.xlsx(data3,file="Output.xlsx",sheetName="abc",append=TRUE)
```

Both overwrite the first 2 worksheets that I would like to keep. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the [`readxl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html) package? **Edit**: do you mean `readxl::read_excel` and `openxlsx::write.xlsx`?

Comment: If `openxlsx::write.xlsx`, have you tried using `startRow=` based on the rows of the first two frames?

Comment: With `openxlsx` writing multiple objects to a workbook typically means you need to create a connection with a workbook, rather than just writing out with `write.xlsx`.  See the vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/vignettes/Introduction.pdf) starting on Page 4

Comment: Though using `loadWorkbook` and eventually `saveWorkbook` is not a requirement, I think Mako212's comment is a good one: there is no need (imho) to repeatedly "*open, find-sheet, write-to-sheet, save*", the internal sequence you're using when you make repeated calls to `write.xlsx`.